# Does the noun "stable" have meanings other than "place for animals"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrases

I came across a Japanese person noting that an English term for the Japanese word "heya" (部屋), the [training area of Sumo wrestlers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heya_%28sumo%29), is "sumo stable", and that "stable" is usually a word used for horses. She found it a bit funny. I'm not sure whether she meant "funny" as in "haha", or "funny" as in "strange".

Wiktionary doesn't have any definitions of [stable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stable#Noun) other than a place for animals, or the horses from a stable.

Do English-speakers really view sumo wrestlers as being like domesticated animals, or is there a meaning of "stable" that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Previously asked on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/110685/1420), but they didn't want it.

Comment: Your question there stayed open long enough to get two good answers (one that is very detailed), plus a smattering of comments. I'd be surprised if there is more to say on the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get the same answer here. We use the word [*stable*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stable) to mean

> "b : a group of people (as athletes, writers, or performers) under one management". It's a sports metaphor, and sumo wrestling is a sport.